# Virtual Host to Allow Encoded Slashes

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

I'm trying to allow encoded slashes on my local pc. But i dont know how to configure virtual host.

**This is my config**

> Apache Version : 2.4.9 (Win64)
>
> PHP Version : 5.5.12

I tried this but it is not working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot localhost/Myapp/
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `DocumentRoot` has to be the absolute physical path of your web app